# Jenkins cannot find pods

Tags: ios, jenkins, cocoapods

```
/usr/local/share/jenkins_agent/workspace/iOS myProject/myProject/User.h:9:9: fatal error: 'Realm/Realm.h' file not found
#import <Realm/Realm.h>
```

Why can it see all my files but is not finding my pods? clueless.

EDIT:
It was because my output folder wasn't in the correct part of the repo and the pods were creating their own output folder, thus not recognising each other. Created an output folder that both could read :)

Answer (score 0):

Likely Jenkins hasn't pulled down your pods.
If you haven't, add a script before your xcode plugin runs in Jenkins with this in it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
source ~/.bash_profile

pod repo update
pod install
```

Comment: you must install cocoapods on the machine that jenkins is installed on.
login or remote into the machine and run :
sudo gem install cocoapods

Comment: It was because my output folder wasn't in the correct part of the repo and the pods were creating their own output folder, thus not recognising each other. My pods were committed to github so they shouldn't have to be pod installed again, thank you though.